# can not read extra from intent when app startup from notification

Tags: android, android-intent, notifications

I am using FCM to receive Messages and on **onMessageReceived**  I have the code

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Service.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            Intent notifyIntent = new Intent(this,HelloBubblesActivity.class);
            notifyIntent.putExtra("id",sender);
            notifyIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK |
                Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, notifyIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);


            NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                    new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                            .setContentTitle("New Message from " + name)
                            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.smalllogo)
                            .setAutoCancel(false)
                            .setContentText(text)
                            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
            notificationManager.notify(sender, mBuilder.build());
```

When the app is opening from the notification I have the problem which is getting extra is -1 as the code here

```
int chatId = getIntent().getIntExtra("id",-1);
```

Did I miss some thing ?

Comment: is your `sender` an `int`?

Comment: yes sure it is int

Comment: Try getting the intent in `onNewIntent` .

Comment: I have just solved it, see my answer down there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As FCM doc

> To receive messages, use a service that extends
>   FirebaseMessagingService. Your service should override the
>   onMessageReceived callback, which is provided for most message types,
>   with the following exceptions:
>
> Notifications delivered when your app is in the background. In this
>   case, the notification is delivered to the device’s system tray. A
>   user tap on a notification opens the app launcher by default. Messages
>   with both notification and data payload. In this case, the
>   notification is delivered to the device’s system tray, and the data
>   payload is delivered in the extras of the intent of your launcher
>   Activity.

so **onMessageReceived** will never trigger if the application in Background and when you click on the notification the MainActivity will launch, all you need is to get the intent and get the Extra as its sent from server

```
if (null != getIntent().getExtras() )
        {
            chatId = getIntent().getStringExtra("sender");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Insure you that your Activity is not singleInstance enable. some time was this problème with singleInstance Activity

Comment: I had put it as android:launchMode="singleTask" not as singleInstance, do you think that is the problem ??

Comment: yes i thing that. Maybe it is due to Android doesn't really refresh Activity. it just bring it to the front. please, try to override onNewIntent(Intent)  in order to intercept new Intent or remove android:launchMode="singleTask" to your Activity